# javaScript issue about "this"

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a game demon, and run into a problem when I'm trying to add a clickEventHanlder to a button, the code goes here:

```
function GameConstructor(){
    this.start = startGame;
    this.count = 5;
    ...
    function startGame(){
        if(this.count > 5){ //here goes the problem, this don't point to the game object when I click the button
            ...
        }
}
...
var game = new GameConstructor(); //game object has a method called start
$("#someBtn").click(game.start); //in the method start this now point to the button so this.count is undefined.
```

I know I can define a global variable count = 5 to solve this, but I just wonder if there is a way to fix in my original way? Thanks.

Comment: you cant access to parent in this case. Cause this is context of current function scope. Use *var* instead

Comment: Using ES6? If yes, use arrow function.

Comment: Using `this` would be out of scope, you could instead use `let`

Comment: `$("#someBtn").click(function(){ game.start() });`  or `this.start = startGame.bind(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a complete JavaScript wizard, but my guess is that the `this` inside your nested function is referring to that nested function, not the outer instance.

Many people opt to create a `self` variable instead, to be a bit more explicit about this scope stuff.  Maybe try this:

```
function GameConstructor(){
    var self = this;    // <-- here, then reference self subsequently
    self.start = startGame;
    self.count = 5;
    ...
    function startGame(){
        if(self.count > 5){ //here goes the problem, this don't point to the game object when I click the button
            ...
        }
}
```

Comment: `this` in a jQuery click event refers to the clicked element.

Comment: `this` almost *never* refers to a function.

Comment: thanks, It works! I was wondering if it's necessary to create a "self" variable every time I build a Constructor?

Comment: @YuDuan - I find it to be a good practice.  It's easier to understand and troubleshoot for many.  With that said, many of the newer JS constructs make this somewhat less of an issue, but for "traditional" JS code, it's common to do so and I consider it a better practice.

Comment: @jdl134679 So in the worst case scenario add a "self" variable will not harm your code at all, is it correct?

Comment: @YuDuan - I wouldn't quite say that... there's umpteen ways to shoot yourself in the foot (with any language, but JavaScript especially), but generally speaking, as a matter of standard practice, there's no reason not to create a separate variable to hold an instance of your object.  `self` just happens to the be unofficial/common name for that variable in this case.

Comment: @jdl134679 I know what you saying, help me a lot!

Comment: (`self` is a common enough name/practice that StackOverflow's syntax highlighter colors it as a keyword, though it's not an actual keyword, just another variable name)

Answer (score 0):

this always point to the current function context in Javascript. Means the lowest function just out of the 'this'. So, you can do like;

```
function GameConstructor(){
    var self= this;
    this.start = startGame;
    this.count = 5;
    ...
    function startGame(){
        if(self.count > 5){ //here goes the problem, this don't point to the game object when I click the button
            ...
        }
}
...
var game = new GameConstructor(); //game object has a method called start
$("#someBtn").click(game.start); //in the method start this now point to the button so this.count is undefined.
```

Comment: I don't think `this` *always* points to the function... it depends upon the calling context, correct?

Comment: `this` in a jQuery click event refers to the clicked element.

Comment: `gameCons` is a _horrible_ name for that aliased copy of `this`.  It's an alias to the _instance_, not the _constructor_.

Comment: ok dudes., I was trying to make the OP undestand this. Thank for -ves

Comment: happy now?? I made it self

Comment: not really, I downvoted due to it saying that this always refers to the function context (which I wasn't convinced is correct)

Comment: @jdl134679 .. thats fine..

Comment: @YuDuan you dont need to create the variable every time. If you give it inside constructor. It will do by itself

Comment: got it, thanks again